# Fetch call on Nextjs 14 gives inconsistent results

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Trying to fetch a list of logs from server. The requests go in correct order but the response are coming in different order.

I have TSx component, I am getting a query search params using useSearchParam() hook and then updating the query param in filter which triggers other useEffect to fetch data, but the fetched data order differs when I reload. Its not consistent.

instance - 1 I get : {count: 10000}, {count: 10000}, {count: 2481}
instance - 2 I get : {count: 10000}, {count: 2481}, {count: 10000}

```
"use client";
// all the imports here

interface SearchFilters {
  q: string;
}

interface SearchResults {
  logEntries: LogEntry[];
  total: number;
}

const SearchPage: React.FC = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const router = useRouter();

  const [searchFilters, setSearchFilters] = React.useState<SearchFilters>({
    q: "",
  });

  // const [logEntries, setLogEntries] = React.useState<LogEntry[]>([]);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = React.useState<SearchResults>({
    logEntries: [],
    total: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const sQuery = searchParams.get("q");
    if (sQuery) {
      setSearchFilters({
        q: sQuery,
      });
    }
  }, [searchParams]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/query" + "?q=" + searchFilters.q)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setSearchResults({
          logEntries: data.data.logs,
          total: data.data.total,
        });
      });
  }, [searchFilters])

  return (
    <main className="flex h-screen flex-col w-full">
      <Navbar />
      <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-center gap-2">
        <div className="w-4/5 mt-4 flex flex-col gap-2">
          <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
            <Input
              value={searchFilters.q}
              onChange={(e) => {
                  setSearchFilters({
                    q: e.target.value,
                  });
              }}
              handleEnter={(query) => {
                router.push(`/search?q=${query}`);
              }}
            />
            <Button text="Search" onClick={() => {}} />
          </div>
          <span className="text-sm text-gray-500">
            About {searchResults.total} results found
          </span>
          <div className="overflow-y-scroll h-[80vh]">
            {searchResults?.logEntries?.map((logEntry, index) => {
              return (
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-1" key={index}>
                  <span className="text-lg font-semibold">
                    {logEntry.level}
                  </span>
                  <span className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                    {logEntry.spanId}
                  </span>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default SearchPage;
```